# Rails inserting double quotes instead of blank string in serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, serialization, yaml

I have an array, example below, that I am serializing into the database and the result is below the example. I've tried using '', "" and nil, the former two insert themselves somehow and nil inserts !!nil which when read back is giving me some weird object.

In my model.

```
serialize :display_instructions
```

In my controller.

```
display_instructions = [["object", '', 5]]
```

The result is below...

```
---
- - places
  - '' 
  - 5
```

If I edit this and remove the '' it works as expected, the problem seems to be on and off. For a while it worked as expected and I got nothing where the quotes are but now it's doing it again.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: As the title suggest, the problem is that it's inserting quotes where I want nothing at all, even using " " inserts the double surrounding quotes.

Jay

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: The title of the question is that it's wrongly inserting two quotes where I want a blank string. If I wanted '' in the database I'd put "''" in the array.

Comment: You haven't said what problem you're actually experiencing. `''` is the correct way to represent an empty string in YAML (`""` or `!!str` are also valid). If you serialize an empty string to YAML that's what it's going to look like, and when you unserialize it you're going to get an empty string back. You would do well to read the YAML spec as well as read up on the differences between the Syck and Psych parsers used by different versions of Ruby.

Comment: When it reads it back, it's not a blank string. I'll inspect and write what I get but to get my desired result from the database I have to remove the '' it's inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to Jordan for tipping me in the correct direction. The problem was in the backend it was only checking nil? and not empty? - problem fixed.

Just to reiterate what he said, '' and "" are how blank strings are represented in YAML.